# Conversion of Surface integral to a suitable Volume integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator

While deriving the Euler's equations of motion in case of Fluid dynamics, I came across this part -

Here $p$ denotes the hydrostatic pressure(scalar function)
I am unable to understand how it transformed this -

$\iint _{\Delta S} - p\hat{n}~ds = -\iiint_{\Delta V} \nabla p~dv$

It says its a consequence of Gauss Divergence theorem but I could try only the below -

$\iint _{\Delta S} - p\hat{n}~ds = \iiint _{\Delta V} \nabla\cdot(-p)~dv$ , but this seems wrong as how can i take the divergence of the scalar function?

Reference - Textbook of Fluid Dynamics by F. Chorlton, page 96, Euler's equation of motion

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't make sense. Where did you see the derivation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the divergence theorem to the vector field $p\,\mathbf{i}$ where $\mathbf{i}$ is the unit basis vector pointing in the $x-$direction.

Noting that $\nabla \cdot (p \, \mathbf{i}) = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x},$ we have

$$\int_S p \,n_x\,dS=\int_S p \mathbf{i} \cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS=\int_V \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\,dV$$

where $\mathbf{n} = n_x \mathbf{i} + n_y \mathbf{j} + n_z \mathbf{k}$ is the normal vector.

Repeat for $p \, \mathbf{j}$ and $p \,\mathbf{k}$. Multiply each result by the appropriate unit basis vector and sum to get

$$\int_S p \,\mathbf{n}\,dS\\= \int_S p(n_x \mathbf{i} + n_y \mathbf{j} + n_z \mathbf{k})\, dS \\=\left(\int_S p \,n_x\,dS\right) \mathbf{i} + \left(\int_S p \,n_y\,dS\right) \mathbf{j} + \left(\int_S p \,n_z\,dS\right) \mathbf{k} \\ =\left(\int_V \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\,dV\right) \mathbf{i} + \left(\int_V  \frac{\partial p}{\partial y}\,dV\right) \mathbf{j} + \left(\int_V \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}\,dV\right) \mathbf{k}\\ = \int_V \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\mathbf{i} +  \frac{\partial p}{\partial y}\mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}\mathbf{k}\right) \, dV\\=\int_V \nabla p \,dV.$$

The general result -- of which the more familiar divergence theorem is a consequence -- is $$\int_V \partial_i f\, dV = \int_S f n_i \, dS$$

Comment: Is $n_{x}$ a vector?

Comment: No $n_x$ is the x-component of the normal vector $\mathbf{n} = n_x \mathbf{i} + n_y \mathbf{j} + n_z \mathbf{k}$.  I use bold-face for vectors, now I see why arrows are sometimes better.

Comment: hm.. how we get this $\int_S p \,\mathbf{n}\,dS=\int_V \nabla p \,dV$ ?

Comment: OK I will put in every step.

Comment: Thanks, In $\int_V \partial_i f\, dV = \int_S f n_i \, dS$, $f$ is  a scalar function right? 2) Also Can I say Gauss Divergence as case basis *) for vector valued - $\int_{S}F.\hat{n} dS = \int_{V}\nabla.F dV$ and *)For Scalar functions $\int_{S} f \hat{n} dS = \int_{V} \nabla f dV$.??

Comment: @BAYMAX: Yes that is correct.  For  a scalar $f$ function, $\int_V \partial_i f dV = \int_S f n_i dS$. Adding together we get the vector form of the theorem, $\int_V \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} dV = \int_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} dS$.