# Euler's equation

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, fluid-dynamics

I am studying fluid mechanics from Landau and Lifshitz and I'm trying to prove the equation $\begin{align*}\\ -\oint \; p\,df = -\int\, grad\,p\,dV\end{align*}\\$ (topic on Euler's equation page 2) which I am running into trouble proving, I was requesting if someone can provide a hint or proof for this equation

Comment: This is a form of the divergence theorem.  The notation here is not entirely clear, but it should equate the volume integral of the pressure gradient over a region to the surface integral of the normally directed pressure  ($p \mathbf{n}$) over the boundary of the region.  Presumably $df$ incorporates the normal vector.  This is proved [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2637260/148510).

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of the analogue of Gauss Divergence Theorem for scalar fields