# Volume integral of gradient field

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I came across the following theorem:

$$ \iint_{\partial \Omega}f dS=\iiint_{\Omega}\nabla{f}dV $$ $\Omega$ is a bounded region whose boundary
$\partial \Omega$ is a closed, piecewise smooth surface which is oriented with an outward normal direction and $f$ is a $C^1$ function in an open region that contains $\Omega$

But I guess I quite don't understand the concept of volume integral of a vector field and it could be that a scalar obtained in the LHS equals a vector obtained in the RHS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not correct. The integrand in the surface integral should be the product of scalar $f$ and the outward normal vector, i.e., $f\mathbf{n}$. This can be derived from the divergence theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2637320/148510).